# Как изменить максимальный и минимальный элементы в строке матрицы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, матрицы

Ниже я привел свой код, он работает неправильно, максимальные и минимальные элементы в строках неправильно поменялись местами, программа нестабильна.

```
number_of_rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows: ")) #matrix generator
m = [[int(j) for j in input("Enter all the elements of a single row (separated by a space): ").split()] for i in range(number_of_rows)]
print("Your matrix : ", *m, sep = '\n')

for i, row in enumerate(m):
    max = min = 0
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        if elem > row[max]:
            max = j
        if elem < row[min]:
            min = j
    row[max], row[0] = row[0], row[max]
    row[min], row[-1] = row[-1], row[min]
print(m)
```

Comment: вы создали список списков, а меняете местами min и max только в последнем элементе... вам нужны вложенные индексы для min и max... или нужно менять в каждом элементе (строке)?

Comment: Можете подробнее пояснить, что вы имеете ввиду под "вложенными индексами для min и max", пожалуйста

Comment: задача в поменять min и max всей матрицы или в каждом вложенном списке (строке)?

Comment: Задача, поменять min и max в каждой строке матрицы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно поменять min и max в каждой строке матрицы (в каждом вложенном списке), попробуйте в конце цикла изменить на:

```
for i, row in enumerate(m):
    max = min = 0
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        if elem > row[max]:
            max = j
        if elem < row[min]:
            min = j
    # row[max], row[0] = row[0], row[max]
    row[min], row[max] = row[max], row[min]

print(m)
```

а то ваш

```
row[max], row[0] = row[0], row[max]
row[min], row[-1] = row[-1], row[min]
```

менял max с первым, а потом min с последним... при:

```
Your matrix : 
[4, 1, 7]
[3, 8, 1]
[13, 42, 77]
```

выдаст:

```
[[4, 7, 1], [3, 1, 8], [77, 42, 13]]
```

Comment: К сожалению, такая же проблема, не работает, в какой-то строке поменяет, а в какой-то нет

Comment: @HateFoube_2002 добавьте в вопрос тестовый кейс и желаемое поведение

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что я ввожу и что хочу увидеть в результате?

Comment: @HateFoube_2002 да, и случай, при котором код из ответа меняет неправильно

Comment: Ваш код работает, спасибо, я сам ошибся